# Multiplex to two file descriptors from a single file descriptor

Tags: c, io, file-descriptor

I have a [library](https://github.com/rustyrussell/ccan/tree/master/ccan/io) that has a rather nice lightweight IO abstraction for things such as TCP connections or `socketpair`, and I am trying to use it to communicate with a subprocess over `stdin` and `stdout`.

The IO library however expects to be able to read and write from the same file descriptor, whereas I have one for reading and one for writing respectively. Now I was wondering if there is a simple way for me to merge the two file descriptors in such a way that it looks like a single fd, but in the background it just multiplexes reads to the `stdout` and writes to the `stdin` of the subprocess.

Is that possible at all, and how much black magic is involved in doing so? Would I be better off to just keep two separate, half-open, connections?

Comment: You'll probably need to do quite a lot of rethinking of your lightweight IO abstraction. It's currently based on 'one file descriptor can do input and output', but needs to be revised to handle 'input requires one file descriptor and output requires a possibly different file descriptor'. Your code will route output operations to the output descriptor, input operations to the input descriptor. You'll probably use your own 'file handle' (which might well be a small integer like a file descriptor is a small integer), but your file handle will not (necessarily) be equal to either file descriptor.

Comment: I was hoping that there is something like `dup2` that'd allow me to duplicate the write side of the `stdin` to `stdout`, but I can't really find anything to that effect.

Comment: Never heard of anything like that — a function call that allows you to treat one file descriptor as reading on one (other) file descriptor and also writing to one (other) file descriptor.  There are read-write file descriptors, of course, but they're not relevant to your context, as I understand it.

Comment: Read-write file descriptors may be one way to deal with your problem, though; OTOH, file positioning may prove intractable.  Sockets and pipes aren't seekable; that alters the file position issues. More seriously, if you write on a socket, only the other end gets to read it.  If you write on the write end of pipe, there's nothing to stop the writer from reading the data from the read end of the pipe.  If you write on a file, any process can read what was written, but you've moved the file position on a read-write file descriptor.

Comment: Can't you create a socketpair, then `fork()` to create the subprocess, then in the child `dup2()` the descriptor of one end of the socketpair to the child's fd 0 and fd 1 (that's two separate calls to `dup2()`)?  After that's done, you can close() that socketpair descriptor, you won't use it any further. Then your i/o library in the parent can read and write on the descriptor for the other end of the socketpair.

Comment: That's sort of what I wanted to avoid, since that'd require some unusual use of `stdin` (or `stdout`) in the child process, whereas I'm trying to keep the child process as close to a normal cli tool possible (i.e., allow interactions from a shell as well).

Comment: @cdecker You would do the `dup2()` manipulation in the forked child process before it invokes `exec()` to run the tool program.  The tool would have no knowledge of those machinations.  It would simply read from `stdin` and write to `stdout` in the usual way, exactly as it would if it had been invoked from a shell.